# Pickle with cucumber, machinist and Mongoid

Tags: cucumber, pickle, mongoid

I'm using pickle 0.3.0 with rails, cucumber and mongoid. I do found that pickle0.3.0 automatically finds the ORM. But while I wrote a cucumber scenario and tested it, It didn't find any pickle steps. 
Here is the sample:

```
Scenario: logging in user
  Given the following users exists
  |name|
  |John|
  |white|
```

But didn't find pickle step

```
# create models from a table
Given(/^the following #{capture_plural_factory} exists?:?$/) do |plural_factory, table|
  create_models_from_table(plural_factory, table)
end
```

and generates this error

```
You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

Given /^the following users should exists$/ do |table|
  # table is a Cucumber::Ast::Table
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Check out this question/answer, I am using mongo mapper but you can probably do something similar with mongoid. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273184/how-do-i-get-cucumber-and-pickle-working-with-mongo-mapper-machinist-and-machin/3283915#3283915

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using pickle 0.4. Error was solved.